# How to remove mapview annotation from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a `MKMapView` with lots of annotations. When I tap on an annotation, the contact details(`ABPersonViewController`) of the annotation is pushed. In this class I have an option to delete the contact. As the contact is deleted from the addressbook, at the same time I need to remove the annotation from the mapview too.

As the delete button is tapped, the contact is removed from the addressbook, and the `ABPersonViewController` class is popped from the navigation stack. Now the user sees the mapview. But it should be without the annotation(contact) which was removed.
How can I do this.

Comment: When you are providing annotation, it must based on some data from AddressBook.So when you remove contact from AddressBook, call the same method to plot annotation which you are calling previously to show annotation.this time it will take updated data and remove annotation for deleted contact.

Comment: Use delegate!! this will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the annotations from the mapview using the `annotation` property. Then iterate through the  annotation list to get the particular annotation then use the

```
- (void)removeAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

method to remove the annotation. I hope it will take care of your problem.

Comment: This method will be in the map view class. How shall I trigger this from a button click in the `ABPersonViewController` class.

Comment: For this you can either create a delegate to do that or you can post a  notification with NSNotificationCenter to the previous previous controller where it will remove the delegate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the annotations in a mutable array and their corresponding address with it like:

> NSMutablearray *array;
>
> [array add object:[NSDictionary dictionarywithobjectandkeys:@"your object and keys"];

Now when the user deletes the address its subsequent annotation will also be deleted. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting all annotation use the code below;

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]
```